# Maximize the distance between a w shaped line construction and two points

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to hang string lights on my rectangular porch in a W-shaped fashion. There are two ceiling fans interrupting the pattern and I need to maximize the distance between the ceiling fan blades and the string lights. The perpendicular distance from the center of each ceiling fan to each line should be equal. I tried to use cad to solve this and I am close but I'd like to get an exact solution if possible. I believe one way to go about it is to use the following Theorem and solve that set of equations along with the equations of the lines. There might also be a derivative involved since we are maximizing something. I began using the theorem and things got pretty nasty right away. I am hoping someone might have a more elegant solution. The unknown variables are x_1, x_2 and x_3.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want `x_3 = 292`?  If so, only the other two x values are unknown.

Comment: @bubba It was a mistake. The new image has now been posted.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few suggestions.

Notation: let’s call the four diagonal lines $L1$, $L2$, $L3$, $L4$, and let’s call the circle centers $C1$ and $C2$. Define some distances $d1 = distance(L1, C1)$, $d2 = distance(L2, C1)$, $d3 = distance(L3, C12)$, and $d4 = distance(L4, C2)$. We want $d1=d2=d3=d4$.

1. Using a CAD system, or even just PowerPoint, you can move the diagonal lines around until the four distances look roughly equal. This would probably be close enough.
2. If your CAD system supports constraint solving, you can dimension the four distances, tell the system you want them to be equal, and let the constraint solver do its thing.
3. You have the formula for the distance from a point to a line, so you can write three equations that express the requirements $d1 = d2$, $d2=d3$ and $d3=d4$. Now we have to solve these three equations to get $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$. Solving these equations by hand is likely to be a big mess, unless someone can spot a clever algebra trick (I can’t). You can try to solve the equations using a computer algebra system like Wolfram Alpha (free) or Mathematica (far from free). If those systems can’t give you an exact algebraic solution, they will at least give you one computed by numerical methods.

Comment: I think calculus can be used because If you pretend to draw the lines by hand you start in the upper left corner and Pick a D1 as a result X1 has been determined by your choice. Let D3=D2=D1, then X2 and X3 have also been determined. At this point D4 has been determined but does not necessarily equal D1. This is because the 4th line in this mental exercise is constrained by the corner point (292,110). I'm thinking you could set it up so that a derivative allows D1 to approach D4. Does this make any sense or would it be more difficult to solve then the algebraic system?

Comment: If you use my approach #3, this all boils down to solving a system of three equations. The numerical methods I mentioned might use derivatives, internally, but we don’t need to see that.

Comment: your cad solution worked please see above

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely be forced to solve numerically no matter what, but here goes:

I'm assuming the optimal solution will have a radius $r$ from the center $C_1$ to the tangent lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ and similarly for $C_2$. I don't know that that's necessarily the case for the optimum, but it's what I'm going with.

For a given $r$, we can calculate $x_1$ by identifying the angle the tangent line $L_1$ makes with the y-axis.
$$x_1 = 110\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\frac{55}{105.5})-\arcsin(\frac{r}{\sqrt{55^2 + 105.5^2}}))$$

$x_3$ can be found the same way.

$$x_3 = 292 - 110\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\frac{55}{81}) - \arcsin(\frac{r}{\sqrt{55^2+81^2}}))$$

Once $x_1$ and $x_3$ are found, we can use the tangent lines $L_2$ and $L_3$ and find their intersections with the top of the rectangle. These won't necessarily agree for a given r, but will give two options $x^L_{2}$ and $x^R_{2}$.

$$x^L_2 = \frac{\sqrt{110^2 + x_1^2} \cdot \sin(2\arcsin(\frac{r}{x_1}))}{\sin(\pi - 2\arcsin(\frac{r}{x_1})-\arctan(\frac{55}{105.5})-\arcsin(\frac{r}{\sqrt{55^2+105.5^2}})}$$

and

$$x^R_2 = 292 - \frac{\sqrt{110^2 + (292-x_3)^2} \cdot \sin(2\arcsin(\frac{r}{x_3}))}{\sin(\pi - 2\arcsin(\frac{r}{x_3})-\arctan(\frac{55}{81})-\arcsin(\frac{r}{\sqrt{55^2+81^2}})}$$

Setting those two equal to each other and solving for $r$ should get you where the tangents meet at a common $x_2$. Barring my tangency assumptions about the optimum being wrong or me misreading the diagram, that gives me $r = 29.6833$, $x_1 = 122.2463$, $x_2 = 149.9779$, and $x_3 = 205.5175$

Answer (score 2):

I put it into CAD. Then checked it against the previous solution. Keep in mind that the tolerance is set to 1/64.

[image]

[image]

Column got in the way!

[image: All that work and a column got in the way!]

Comment: A numerical solution is going to be the best you can do. After doing out too much algebra:

$x_1 = 122.2463009839560914669064355869597068\dots$ is the real solution of $$2984x^7-2203684x^6+803626114x^5-180830349625x^4+27280292057176x^3-2754957086055401x^2+175453649542580508x-5533650079159662376=0$$

and doesn't seem to have a solution in radicals.

Comment: @MichaelBiro your solution worked. See above.